# How to add params to url in rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to integrate an input form to do research. We can have different params inside the URL so I need to make that the search is working and does not erase the rest of the params.

URL at the begining :
http://localhost:3000/?concept%5B%5D=art

Action desire : 
When I press enter it create a params named :”search”

[image]

Current code for the input form is :

How can I make below final result using link_to.

Final result should look like this :
http://localhost:3000/?search=XXXX&concept%5B%5D=art

Comment: A simple solution would to be to add a hidden input to the form for each param that you want to "forward".

Comment: And you can add any amount of query string parameters with link to by just passing a hash. `link_to "text", path, search: a, concept: b ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add hidden field to your form:

```
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'concept[]', 'art' %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'search' %>
```